# Getting the color of a pixel in an ImageView in Android

Tags: android, android-imageview, getpixel

I am trying to get the color of the spot where I touched on an ImageView. And I succeeded using getPixel(x,y) for getting the color, but on another spot I am not getting the color of the pixel where I touched; I am getting the color of a different pixel.

ImageView xml:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ImgSelected"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo" />
```

Assigning Bitmap to ImageView:

```
imageViewSelected.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_INSIDE);
imageViewSelected.setImageBitmap(bm2);
```

OnTouch() for getting the pixel

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {

        if (imageViewSelected.getVisibility() == 0) {
            float eventX = event.getX();
            float eventY = event.getY();
            float[] eventXY = new float[] { eventX, eventY };

            Matrix invertMatrix = new Matrix();
            imageViewSelected.getImageMatrix().invert(invertMatrix);

            invertMatrix.mapPoints(eventXY);
            int x = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[0]);
            int y = Integer.valueOf((int) eventXY[1]);

            Drawable imgDrawable = imageViewSelected.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = ((BitmapDrawable) imgDrawable).getBitmap();

            // Limit x, y range within bitmap
            if (x < 0) {
                x = 0;
            } else if (x > bitmap.getWidth() - 1) {
                x = bitmap.getWidth() - 1;
            }

            if (y < 0) {
                y = 0;
            } else if (y > bitmap.getHeight() - 1) {
                y = bitmap.getHeight() - 1;
            }

            int touchedRGB = bitmap.getPixel(x, y);
            ImgColorPublic.touchX = (int) event.getX();
            ImgColorPublic.touchY = (int) event.getY();
            ImgColorPublic.touchColor = Integer.toHexString(touchedRGB);

        }
        return false;
    }
```

Using this code, for some images I am getting the correct value, but not for all images.

Comment: sorry i read above the if statements

Comment: does ImageView use paddings?

Comment: @pskink No. No padding.

Comment: so are int x, y computed correctly?

Comment: Ya i think so. Because i can draw a circle where i touched, only pixel is getting wrong

Comment: We should really find out more about when it goes wrong before we hypothesize. Let's narrow it down. Could you just for now change the ImageView's width and height to be exactly equals to in px of one of your bitmaps. Does it work then?

Comment: @JMIndia have u solved this problem yet. I am having same problem too.

Comment: http://android-er.blogspot.in/2013/08/get-bitmap-color-on-touched-position-in.html